# Stream error, while trying to initialize deflate object in Compress::Raw::Zlib::_deflateInit

Tags: mysql, perl, zlib

I have faced a strange issue in an application using `PDF::API2` Perl module on CentOS 7 system (perl-5.16). Whenever it tries to use `openpage()` function it gets:

```
Can't call method "inflate" on an undefined value at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/PDF/API2/Basic/PDF/Filter/FlateDecode.pm line 49.
```

I tried to reproduce the issue using simple calls to `PDF::API2`, but couldn't trigger the error:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use PDF::API2;

print "Content-Type: application/pdf\n\n";

my $pdf = PDF::API2->open('/tmp/test.pdf');

my $page = $pdf->openpage(1);

print $pdf->stringify();
```

Next, I used the application's own high-level call in my simple script and I was able to trigger the issue. Well, I decided to use Perl debugger to find any differences and ended up in Zlib's `deflateInit` subroutine (`/usr/share/perl5/Compress/Zlib.pm`), especially in `Compress::Raw::Zlib::_deflateInit`:

```perl
my $obj ;

my $status = 0 ;
($obj, $status) = 
  Compress::Raw::Zlib::_deflateInit(0,
            $got->getValue('level'), 
            $got->getValue('method'), 
            $got->getValue('windowbits'), 
            $got->getValue('memlevel'), 
            $got->getValue('strategy'), 
            $got->getValue('bufsize'),
            $got->getValue('dictionary')) ;

my $x = ($status == Z_OK() ? bless $obj, "Zlib::OldDeflate"  : undef) ;
```

As I understand, it is a low-level call to zlib C library. Here I found that the object is not created because of 'stream error' `$status`, when I use the high-level calls of the application. Although, the arguments passed (level, method and so on) are absolutely the same in both cases. I couldn't use Perl debugger any further inside `Compress::Raw::Zlib::_deflateInit`, so it is a black box for me now.

I firmly believe that the application changes some aspects of Perl's behavior, but I couldn't find any. I found out that 'stream error' is returned when the first argument is `NULL` (in C context) or invalid value for level is passed. I am sure the level is correct and is actually the same in both cases (successful and failed). Next, I thought about the first argument, which is zero (`0`).

Is it possible that the application changes something in Perl so it treats passed `0` (zero) argument differently? How can I debug the issue further inside `Compress::Raw::Zlib::_deflateInit`?

UPDATE:

I went on debugging C code called by `Compress::Raw::Zlib::_deflateInit` using `gdb` and found that `/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/auto/Compress/Raw/Zlib/Zlib.so` calls `deflateReset` function from `/usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.18.1.0` library instead of `/usr/lib64/libz.so.1.2.7`.

Now it is clear why my test code could not trigger the error, it does not use MySQL functions. However, code in the application use a lot of MySQL calls before `PDF::API2` functions.

I use MySQL community server installed from official repository:

```
$ rpm -qa | grep mysql
mysql-community-libs-5.6.43-2.el7.x86_64
mysql-community-server-5.6.43-2.el7.x86_64
mysql80-community-release-el7-2.noarch
mysql-community-common-5.6.43-2.el7.x86_64
mysql-community-client-5.6.43-2.el7.x86_64
```

Now I have got new questions. Did MySQL community incorrectly bundle `Zlib` code into `libmysqlclient.so`? What can I do as a systems administrator to solve the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you have multiple installations of Perl or `Compress::Raw::Zlib` and your test code and the application use different versions? BTW: C `NULL` is usually defined as `(void *) 0`, i.e. passing a `0` as pointer parameter to a C API would be equivalent to `NULL`.

Comment: No, I don't. I use minimal CentOS environment with system-provided Perl 5.16.

`# grep -FRIn 'package Compress::Raw::Zlib' /usr/  
/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/Compress/Raw/Zlib.pm:2:package Compress::Raw::Zlib;
  
# rpm -qa | grep -i zlib  
perl-Compress-Raw-Zlib-2.061-4.el7.x86_64
zlib-1.2.7-18.el7.x86_64`

Answer (score 1):

Well, after several days of debugging it became evident that the core issue is in `libmysqlclient.so` library, supplied by MySQL community server. The library is statically linked against `zlib` and it exports all `zlib` symbols globally. As a result, any binary with loaded `zlib.so` and `libmysqlclient.so` at the same time would have a chance to call a `zlib` function from `libmysqlclient.so`, rather than from `zlib.so`.

The related [bug report](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=94725) has been opened and approved now (unfortunately, as a feature request).

As I workaround I switched to MariaDB 10.2 from Red Hat Software Collections.